# I can't see html components in browser

Tags: jsf, maven, primefaces

I couldn't see neither primefaces nor html components in my page. I can see only "sdaf" string. What can be the problem? At index.xhtml page autocomplete works good I can see component names. There must be nothing wrong with libraries.

My index.xhtml file;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

<h:head>  

</h:head>  

<h:body>  
  <h:button value="html button"> </h:button>
  sdaf
    <p:spinner />  

</h:body>  
</html>
```

my pom.xml file;

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-     v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>5454</groupId>
<artifactId>45454</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>45454 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
 <repository>  
  <id>prime-repo</id>  
 <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
<url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
<layout>default</layout>  
</repository>  
 </repositories>

<dependencies>
<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
  <version>3.5</version>  
</dependency> 

   <dependency>
<groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <finalName>45454</finalName>
</build>
 </project>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking that you need to see the html code when right clicking your browser & view source?

Comment: @Ajeesh I edited my topic. When I run my project, I can't see button and slider in page. There is only text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to see whether you can see inputtext box and a command button,

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

 <f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>Title Goes Here</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
   <h:form>
            <p:panel header="Send">
                <p:inputText value="Hi"></p:inputText>
                <p:commandButton value="Send" id="btnDisplay"/> 
            </p:panel>

            </h:form>


    </h:body>

</f:view>
 </html>
```

**Web.xml**

You need to have the below lines in your web.xml file

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I can't see anything in the page. Just see page title.

Comment: What are all the jar files you have in your classpath & which ide are you using.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. I also added screenshot of my project structure.

Comment: I deleted Tomcat server config. from Eclipse and now I coudn't create a new one. When I solved this problem, I will look your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem could be your 'URL' if in your web.xml you have mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
```

then you need to add 'faces' to your url. For example:

```
:http://localhost:8080/ABC/faces/pages/login.xhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have not rendered the requested api like `jsf-impl` to your `pom.xml` for reference check [Primefaces-Maven-Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/primefaces-hello-world-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your elements to show on page into the form tag:

```
<h:form>
 <h:button value="html button"> </h:button>
  sdaf
 <p:spinner/>
</h:form>
```